# Basic simplifcation

Tags: mathematical-economics

This may be a simple question, but how is [image] simplified to [image]

With the rules of simplification, do both the terms on the left hand side get multiplied by q^2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you can multiply both sides by $q^2$ and you get $-100+q^2$ on the left-hand side and $0 \cdot q^2 = 0$ on the right.

Another way.

$$-100/q^2 + 1 = 0 \iff 1 = 100/q^2 \iff q^2 = 100 \iff q^2 - 100 = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

What you actually do is multiply both sides of the equation by $q^2$.

This works because $0 \cdot q^2 = 0$.

Comment: Many thanks that helps